# Usar una variable global que usa variables dentro

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una variable global que se llama body, que voy a usar en mas de una función cambiando dos parámetros dentro de esta. La idea entonces es definir la variable al comienzo y dentro de ella dejar dos variables que les daremos valor en cada función, aquí el ejemplo:

```
//Creo una variable con la url de pruebas
const base_url ='https://192.168.1.10/_pxc_api/api/variables'
//Creo una variable que modificaré en cada función con el valor correspondiente
var valor
//Creo yna variable que modificaré en cada funcion con el path correspondiente
var path
//Creo una variable para el body del put en función de las variables
var body = {
  "pathPrefix": "Arp.Plc.Eclr/",
  "variables":
  [
    {
      "path": `${path}`,
      "value": `${valor}`,
      "valueType": "Constant"
    }
  ]
} 
//función escritura de variable
function changevar(){
  valor = document.getElementById("bCaldera").checked
  path = "bCaldera"
    fetch(base_url,{
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
  }
```

El problema es que tal y como está el código me devuelve la variable con las variables de dentro como undefined.

Comment: Son undefined porque no tenian asignado nada en el momento que has creado la variable body.

Comment: como puedo modificarlo entonces? dando un valor por defecto que luego cambie en cada variable?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que pretendes es que body contenga el valor de **path** y **valor** justo antes de lanzar el fetch, podrías hacerlo así:

```
function changevar(){
  body.variables[0].path = path
  body.variables[0].value = valor
  valor = document.getElementById("bCaldera").checked
  path = "bCaldera"
    fetch(base_url,{
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
  }
```

de esta forma se actualiza su contenido en el momento que se invoca a la función.

### Actualización

Gracias al aporte de @Benito-B otra posible solución seria reformular el código usando una función que evite posibles errores durante el uso de la variable **body**, sustituyéndola por una función. Por ejemplo quedaría así:

```
//Creo una variable con la url de pruebas
const base_url = 'https://192.168.1.10/_pxc_api/api/variables'
//Creo una variable que modificaré en cada función con el valor correspondiente
var valor
//Creo yna variable que modificaré en cada funcion con el path correspondiente
var path
//Creo una función para el body del put en función de las variables
function body() {
  return {
    "pathPrefix": "Arp.Plc.Eclr/",
    "variables": [{
      "path": `${path}`,
      "value": `${valor}`,
      "valueType": "Constant"
    }]
  }
}
//función escritura de variable
function changevar() {
  valor = document.getElementById("bCaldera").checked
  path = "bCaldera"
  fetch(base_url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(body())
  })
}
```

donde la nueva función **body()** podría ser invocada en cada uso y actualizar correctamente los datos de las otras variables en ese momento.

Comment: Yo creo que aquí lo correcto sería tener una función que devuelva un string template 
del body ya correctamente montado y olvidarse de variables "globales" (y de usar `var`)

Comment: @Benito-B Listo, he actualizado mi respuesta con lo que he entendido que querias decir con tu aporte

Comment: Cuasi es lo que decía yo. Me refería a declarar la función tal que así: `body(valor, path) {...}`, y te evitas tener declaradas las variables `var valor` y `var path`, el uso de variables "globales" es poco mantenible y puede dar errores cuando no sabes desde dónde la estás modificando en cada momento. De esta manera, coges el valor y se lo pasas a la función que te devuelve el payload ya bien, y no hay necesidad de usar variables externas. :)

Comment: Ya, tienes razón, pero entiendo que las quiere así, globales, de ahí su pregunta, pues las debe tener globales porque las estará usando de ese modo en otras partes del código. De todos modos aun no se ha pronunciado sobre esta respuesta, ya veremos que dice y si lo convencemos que no las use globales sino que las vaya parametrizando en todas partes

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de definir la variable `body`, tanto `path` como `valor` son `undefined` y eso no cambia después, porque `body` no se va a "actualizar" solo, a menos que, como han dicho, se use una función. Entre las muchas posibilidades para que `body` se mantenga "actualizado" está la de convertir a los valores en funciones, lo que sería similar a un *getter* en una clase:

```js
let valor = "valor inicial";

const body = {
  "prop": () => valor // --> devuelve el valor que tiene en el momento de llamar la propiedad
}

function changevar() {

  valor = "cambiamos variable global";
  console.log(body.prop());

}

changevar();
```

Si bien esta es una posibilidad, idealmente en mi opinión es mas legible cambiar directamente el valor de `body`, algo como `body.prop = "nuevo valor"`

Comment: Me gusta tu solución, gracias por el aporte!